# C# читка с xml файла

Tags: c#, xml, парсер

Очень нужна помощь. У меня есть файл xml со следующей структурой

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Head xmlns="http://www.sample-package.org">
    <Number>748</Number>
    <Number_confirm>977</Number_confirm>
    <Positions>
        <Tare_id>2442</Tare_id>
    </Positions>
    <Positions>
        <Product_id>168813</Product_id>
    </Positions>
</Head>
```

Нужно пройтись по файлу и добавить в словарь ключик и значение (N и "Number"), (id и Product_id).

```
//открываем xml
doc.Load(temp);

var root = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Head");
var documents = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
for (int i = 0; i <root.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < root[i].ChildNodes.Count; j++)
    {

        var element = root[i].ChildNodes[j];
        InfoManager.MessageBox("element:{0}", element.Value);
        var document = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        document.Add("N", element.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Number"));
        document.Add("NC", element.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Number_confirm"));
        documents.Add("ID",
        element.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Product_id"));
        documents.Add(document);

    }

}
```

у меня element.Attributes пишет null, MessageBox показывает element пустой и не все елементы добавляет в словарь. как можно это исправить и вывести весь словарь??

Comment: решение данного вопроса находится тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408291/how-to-read-the-xml-file-and-write-to-the-dictionary

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    private static string _xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
                    <Head xmlns = 'http://www.sample-package.org'>
                        <Number>748</Number>
                        <Number_confirm>977</Number_confirm>
                        <Positions>
                            <Tare_id>2442</Tare_id>
                        </Positions >
                        <Positions>
                            <Product_id>168813</Product_id>
                        </Positions>
                    </Head>";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XElement doc = XElement.Parse(_xml);
        XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.sample-package.org");

        var N = doc.Element(ns + "Number").Value;
        var NC = doc.Element(ns + "Number_confirm").Value;
        var ID = doc.Elements(ns + "Positions").Last().Value;

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add(nameof(N), N);
        dict.Add(nameof(NC), NC);
        dict.Add(nameof(ID), ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: подскажите, а что даст ns + "Positions" и зачем в namespace писать урл сайта?

Comment: Это не url сайта, а пространство имен этого xml, просто по традиции эти названия пишут в таком формате. Когда в xml объявлено пространство имен вот так: xmlns = 'http://www.sample-package.org', то припарсенге такого xml требуется использовать это в имени каждого элемента.